# Casting between std::array types

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

I've been playing around a bit with std::array, and while I don't actually want to do that, I discovered that the following seems to work - at least in my tests:

```
void f(std::array<int,5>& x); //function doing stuff on an array of length 5

std::array<int,10> a;

//do some stuff with a

f(*reinterpret_cast<std::array<int,5>*>(&a)); //apply f to first half of a

//...
```

Admittedly, on first glance this looks sort of dangerous. However, I could imagine that it will work on all implementations of std::array (as long as you don't cast to a longer array, of course).

Is this actually a safe thing to do? If not, what could go wrong?

If it turns out to be safe, is there any way of doing it to the second half of the array?

Comment: It's not totally out of reason trying to slice std::array. That's a good container to base some ℝ^n algebra on it, and for e.g. interfacing with legacy apps it may be useful to have easy access to vectors of its sub-spaces. Thus I posted an ansatz in the old thread.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth The answers in the "duplicate" are not all that convincing.  Is that the best duplicate you can find?